# How can I filter products by meta in Woocommerce REST API?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I want filter products by meta_data in woocommerce rest api. I tried this, but not working:

```
            $data = array(
                'numberposts'   => -1,
                'post_type'     => 'product',
                'meta_query' => array(
                    'relation'      => 'AND',
                    array(
                        'key'       => 'package_type',
                        'value'     => $filters['ad_type'],
                        'compare'   => '='
                    ),
                    array(
                        'key'       => 'package_location',
                        'value'     => $filters['ad_location'],
                        'compare'   => '='
                    ),
                    array(
                        'key'       => 'package_price_range',
                        'value'     => $filters['ad_price_range'],
                        'compare'   => '='
                    )
                )
            );

$_results = $this->woocommerce->get('products', $data);
```

It seems the $data filter is not prevail, it will get back the all product without filter. So the questions is, how can i use meta filters in api request?

Comment: Not possible using woocommerce API, it does not have a meta query parameter. What you can do is write your own endpoint and process your request using PHP methods woocommerce provides.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution.
Extend/override woocommerce/packages/woocommerce-rest-api/src/Controllers/Version3/class-wc-rest-products-controller.php controller,

put the following:

```
if ( ! empty( $request['custom_filter'] && ! empty( $request['meta_key'] ) ) ) {
    $args['meta_query'] = $this->add_meta_query( $args, array(
        'key'     => $request['meta_key'],
        'value'   => $request['meta_value'],
        'compare' => '=',
    ) );
}
```

and tada.wav you can filter by meta_query!

Comment: but if we are using woo rest api using consumer key/secret and calling from external source, how to override this? pls advise.